# Sublime text file bar missing

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

You can see below the picture with my problem... Idk what I changed but is not showing the opened files anymore, anyone know how to fix it? I'm using ST3

[image: sublime screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figure out. Aha.

Menu -> View -> Show Tabs

Comment: I just did and the problem persists :(

Comment: @FabioPicheli when set to default theme, did your file bars come back? If so, the problem is the theme you installed, try another theme.

Comment: No they don't, keep equal the picture but with the default theme

Comment: @FabioPicheli try this, menu bar -> View -> Show Tabs

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the help, I didn't found this option on the menu.